# text box should not accept multiple 0 if the first digit is already 0

Tags: html, vb.net

the text box accepts multiple 0 when the first digit is already a 0

```
<asp:TemplateColumn>
         <HeaderTemplate>
             Consumed
         </HeaderTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:TextBox ID="txtConsumed" runat="server" CausesValidation="true"></asp:TextBox>
             <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvtxtQty" runat="server" 
                 ControlToValidate="txtConsumed" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="*Required" 
                 ValidationGroup="Val_Packages" />
             <ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender27" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtConsumed"
 FilterType="Numbers" Enabled="True" />
             <br />
         </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

I need textbox to show only 1 "0" when I press 0 many times.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code. The KeyPress event triggers code that will not allow any non-digit characters and the KeyUp event triggers code that removes all but one leading zero.  It will work while you input the text as you requested.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyUp
    If Mid(TextBox1.Text, 1, 1) = "0" Then
        If Mid(TextBox1.Text, 2, 1) = "0" Then
            TextBox1.Text = Mid(TextBox1.Text, 2, Len(TextBox1.Text) - 1)
        Else
        End If
    Else
    End If
    TextBox1.SelectionStart = Len(TextBox1.Text) + 1
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    e.Handled = Not (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Or Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Jamie, will it also works while typing zeros in the textbox? I need the zeros remove during the time im typing it...

Comment: @Nick I have edited my answer.  It will now work while you are typing in the textbox.  I also added code to allow only numeric input.

Comment: Why the empty Else?

Comment: Have a look at SubString. It is the .net way of doing the old VB6 Mid method. It will be helpful to know when you need to code in C#.

Comment: I am not very familiar with ASP.net but I don't think the TextBox has key events.

Comment: hi thanks for the answer, I actually use this regexp instead.

Comment: <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" id="rexNumber" controltovalidate="txtConsumed" validationexpression="(?!^(00).*$)^\d+$" errormessage="Error!" />

Answer (score 0):

Ive use a regexvalidator. Here is the link to try it.

https://regex101.com/r/wV9mD8/23